# Correct way to pass cascading parameter value from parent to child/grandchild components in Blazor?

Tags: .net, blazor

I'm newbie to Blazor (dotnet 8 rc2) and wonder why the child component like TeamStandings could be loaded with null CascadingParameter currentSeason ?

DataLayout:

```
@if (currentSeason!=null && currentSeason.ActiveCategory.IsActive)
{
    <CascadingValue Value="@currentSeason">          
        @Body
    </CascadingValue>
}
@code {
   
    [CascadingParameter]
    RouteData RouteData { get; set; }
    public string? Slug { get; set; }
    public CurrentSeasonModel? currentSeason { get; set; } = new();
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (RouteData.RouteValues.TryGetValue("Slug", out var slug) == true)
        {
           // update currentSeason
        }
     }

}
```

Parent page:

```
@page "/abc"
    @if (currentSeason != null && currentSeason.ActiveCategory.IsActive)
    {
    
        <TTSWeb.Blazor.Client.Pages.League.RecentFixtures />
        <TTSWeb.Blazor.Client.Pages.League.TeamStandings  />
     
    }
    @code {
     
        [CascadingParameter]
        public CurrentSeasonModel? currentSeason { get; set; }
    }
```

On TeamStandings component:
[image]

Comment: This is blazor 8 are your components all the same render type is there a mix?

Comment: @BrianParker for this page, the parent page is on the main project, just like above info. For components from Client, they're all InteractiveAuto. For other page, I have client components mixed with different render types

Answer (score 2):

If you don't set it then it's null. That is what the error says. You haven't shown `TeamStandings` so anything else is guesswork.

You have two solutions:

1. Set the `[CascadingParameter]` to a value where you define it.
2. Set the `[CascadingParameter]` to a value before you attempt to use it.
3. Test to see that it's set before any rendering takes place and throw and error if null.

```cs
<h3>MyComponent</h3>

@code {
    // This sets it to default - which is null bit we tell the compiler that we know better
    [CascadingParameter] private string Value { get; set; } = default!;

    public override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(parameters);

        // Before we do any rendering check to make sure that Value is set and throw an exception if it's not
        // This will only normally occur during Development
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(Value);

        return base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
    }
}
```

### Additional Info

I've just noticed that your Cascade declaration in TeamStandings is

```cs
[CascadingParameter] CurrentSeasonModel currentSeason { get; set; }
```

While your cascaded value is of type `CurrentSeasonModel?`.

Different types: one is a nullable other other isn't!  There's even the green warning [I missed it too!].

Comment: thanks, but I already updated the CascadingParameter on the DataLayout. All components should inherit the cascading parameter from this layout, doesn't it?

Comment: See updated comment on diffferent types.

Comment: that doesnt change anything, still the same. at first i use the same types, I just try different type to see if it can enforce the binding value not null

Comment: Without seeing a lot more code, I don't have any more suggestions.  It works, so you're doing something wrong.